# Can you use the path from Copy Link to Highlight to focus on a certain element of a page but without that element being highlighted?

Tags: reactjs, focus, href

I am using "copy link to highlight" in my href to to focus on a certain element, but I don't want that element to be highlighted.

I am working in next.js. When a user clicks a link, I want the page to open in up in a new tab and focus on a certain paragraph on the page.

The issue is that the page the user is directed to to after clicking the link is not managed in our codebase, but wordpress, which I don't have access to. This also means that there is not a document object. So, using document.getElementBy.... gives me a reference error.

As a possible solution, I am using chrome's "copy link to highlight" and using that as my href. This works to focus on the correct area of the page, but, I don't want that area of the page to be highlighted.

Is there a way to alter the URL to remove the highlight on the focused element?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you're unable to modify the code on the destination page, and you're relying on Chrome's "copy link to highlight" feature to focus on a specific element, there is no direct way to alter that I don't think.

However, you probably can use JavaScript to remove the focus from the element once the page loads.

You can try adding this script to the pages where you want to remove the highlight:

```
<script>
  window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    const elementId = urlParams.get('highlight');
    
    if (elementId) {
      const element = document.getElementById(elementId);
      if (element) {
        element.blur();
      }
    }
  });
</script>
```

When creating the URL for the link that should focus on the desired paragraph, append a query parameter to the URL. For example:

```
<a href="https://example.com/page#paragraph1?highlight=paragraph1">Link</a>
```

In this example, `paragraph1` is both the ID of the targeted paragraph and the value of the `highlight` query parameter. Adjust the values as per your specific scenario.

By using the script, the DOMContentLoaded event is triggered when the page loads. It retrieves the highlight query parameter from the URL and checks if it matches any element's ID on the page. If there's a match, it removes the focus from the element, effectively removing the highlight.

Hope that helps.